# first product not added in session

Tags: php

Hi Iam creating a simple php shopping cart application in which the items are shown initially and when the user clicks add to cart it is added the cart.The problem is except first product everything is added to the cart.The first product alone showing erreor on adding.
Could anyone help me to fix this problem soon
here is my code
my chooseproduct.php

```
<div class="products">
<?php

include "config.php";
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
 $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$query3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `catalouge` where subcat_id='$subcat_id'");

if ($query3) { 
while($obj = $query3->fetch_object())
    {




        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update3.php">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><a href=product_view.php?product_code='.$obj->product_code.'><img src="admin/'.$obj->product_image.'"></a></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
         echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->description.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo 'Price '.$currency.$obj->product_price.' | ';
        echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';
        echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

```
<div class="shopping-cart">
<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
 {
$total = 0;
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
    echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update3.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
    echo '<h3>'.$cart_itm["name"].'</h3>';
    echo '<div class="p-code">P code : '.$cart_itm["code"].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="p-price">Price :'.$currency.$cart_itm["price"].'</div>';
    echo '</li>';
    $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
}
echo '</ol>';
echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> <a href="viewcart.php">Check-out!</a></span>';
echo '<span class="empty-cart"><a href="cart_update3.php?    emptycart=1&return_url='.$current_url.'">Empty Cart</a></span>';
 }else{
   echo 'Your Cart is empty';
   }
  ?>
 </div>

  </div>

cart_update3.php

  <?php
  session_start();
  include_once("config.php");

 //empty cart by distroying current session
 if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
 {
$return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
session_destroy();
header('Location:'.$return_url);
  }

//add item in shopping cart
   if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
     {
   $product_code    = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);     //product code
$product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
$return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url

//limit quantity for single product
if($product_qty > 10){
    die('<div align="center">This demo does not allowed more than 10 quantity!<br /><a href="http://sanwebe.com/assets/paypal-shopping-cart-integration/">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
}

//MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_price FROM catalouge WHERE product_code='$product_code LIMIT 1'");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();

if ($results) { //we have the product info 

    //prepare array for the session variable
    $new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$obj->product_price));

    if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) //if we have the session
    {
        $found = false; //set found item to false

        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
        {
            if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code){ //the item exist in array

                $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"],      'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                $found = true;
            }else{
                //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrive old info and prepare array for session var
                $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
            }
        }

        if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
        {
            //add new user item in array
            $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
        }else{
            //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
            $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
        }

    }else{
        //create a new session var if does not exist
        $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
    }

}

//redirect back to original page
header('Location:'.$return_url);
```

}

```
  //remove item from shopping cart
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) &&   isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
$product_code   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
$return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
{
    if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code){ //item does,t exist in the list
        $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
    }

    //create a new product list for cart
    $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
}

//redirect back to original page
header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
?>
```

Comment: What error is shown when attempting to add the first product?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the page is not showing any errors. but the first product fetched from the database is not added to the cart.except the first one all are adding